# Start Nant from code

Tags: c#, build, nant

I am trying to start Nant using C# code. The same string entered in command line works fine but it won't work from code. Here is the code I am using

```
StringWriter consoleOut = new StringWriter( );
Console.SetOut( consoleOut );

ConsoleDriver.Main( new string[] { "-buildfile:" + filePath });
```

I am using nant.core to build the files externaly but it wont work... If I use the same command in cmd everything goes well... Starting it from code i get the following message

> {NAnt 0.91 (Build 0.91.3881.0; alpha2;
>   17.08.2010.)\r\nCopyright ( C) 2001-2010 Gerry
>   Shaw\r\nhttp://nant.sourceforge.net\r\n\r\n\r\nFor
>   more information regarding the cause
>   of the build failure, run the build
>   again in debug mode.\r\n\r\nTry 'nant
>   -help' for more information\r\n}

watching -help too but didnt find anything usefull :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shell out to your executable that you would normally call from the command line:

```
            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo( executable, parameters )
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardError = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            using( var process = Process.Start( startInfo ) )
            {
                if( process != null )
                {
                    process.WaitForExit( timeoutInMilliSeconds );
                    return process.ExitCode;
                }
            }
```

Comment: looks good... ill do some tests before i give you the checkmark :) just one more question... maybe a bit silly.. but this will also work using asp.net mvc on a web server? :)

Comment: just found out that there is one problem... if the path has spaces like "Documents\Visual Studio 2010" then it wont work... if the path has no spaces then it works fine... this problem is also in cmd present... any suggestions?

Comment: Assuming the Asp.net web server is running under the context of a user with enough priveleges to run your executable, yes.

Comment: I wouldn't have expected that to matter, but you can try surrounding the executable string with escaped quotation marks? e.g. `executable = "\"" + executable + "\""` ?  I assume you're referring to the path of the executable?

Comment: looks like it works fine now without any changes to the path... i dont know how but it's working:) thanks a lot man:)